# Rstudio not executing from terminal on ubuntu after installing

Tags: r, ubuntu, rstudio

I have installed rstudio using steps below:

```sh
~$ sudo apt update
~$ sudo apt-get install r-base
~$ sudo apt install gdebi-core
//Downloaded the latest Ubuntu RStudio, `rstudio-server-1.3.959-amd64.deb`
~$ ls
rstudio-server-1.3.959-amd64.deb
~$ sudo gdebi rstudio-server-1.3.959-amd64.deb
```

After it installed finally to run rstudio

```sh
~$ rstudio
rstudio: command not found
```

It is showing command not found. Is there any other thing we need to do?

Comment: I strongly recommend following the instructions that rstudio provides https://docs.rstudio.com/resources/install-r/

Comment: is RStudio on $PATH after installation? what is the result of : echo $PATH

Comment: @Bruno, I have tried this, it install R, which was already there as well, but doesn't install rstudio

Comment: @Waldi 
The output of echo $PATH:
/home/archit/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/snap/bin

Comment: as Rstudio folder in not in your $PATH, the rstudio command can't work if you are not in the directory where RStudio is installed

Comment: Please help me, How to add Rstudio in $PATH

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have installed rstudio-server not rstudio.

To install rstudio:

$ wget https://download2.rstudio.org/server/bionic/amd64/rstudio-se

$ sudo gdebi rstudio-1.3.959-amd64.deb

To run rstudio after installation:

$ rstudio